# How to add the property of same occurrence of object in an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey everyone I have this data coming from an API source what you can see here you will find some duplicate for each of the object what I want is, I want to add the `stars & destructionPercentage` with the once which matches with its duplicate. Since the property `name` can be changed anytime. I want to do the match with the property `tag` since its unique and will never change, so what will happen here is as you can see a clan name of Air Hounds 3 you will find another object with Air Hounds 3 down below. so the first AirHounds 3 has a `star` 9  and a `destructionPercenatge` of 23.46 now there is another Air Hounds 3 with a value of `stars` 39 and a `destructionPercentage` of 76.6 so what I want is I want to add this `stars & destructionPercentage` of 2 objects and want to return the sum of it as 1 object in a new array with all other properties it has in the object, this rule will be applied to all the other 7 datas with their matching their duplicated once. Note currently there is 1 occurrence of duplicate but there will more in future I want the same to work for them as well. So there is currently 16 objects so it should return 8. If there is more than 16 objects like 24 or 32 or even more it should no matter what it is it should return 8 Can anyone tell me how can I do it. Thanks in Advance.

here is the data:

```js
[
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: '一群爷们在战斗',
    tag: '#PQYGYLPJ',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png'
    },
    stars: 2,
    destructionPercentage: 4.933333333333334
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: '雨过天晴',
    tag: '#R8JRUJCU',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png'
    },
    stars: 12,
    destructionPercentage: 35.13333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: '宝贝轻点',
    tag: '#2PU8GLGGL',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png'
    },
    stars: 3,
    destructionPercentage: 5.333333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: 'ubw',
    tag: '#9LY9YLQV',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png'
    },
    stars: 36,
    destructionPercentage: 80
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: 'Air Hounds 3',
    tag: '#2P9UG82L',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png'
    },
    stars: 15,
    destructionPercentage: 39.93333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: '青春无敌',
    tag: '#9LLVCP9V',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png'
    },
    stars: 4,
    destructionPercentage: 7.933333333333334
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: 'blue vapor',
    tag: '#GJ98C29G',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png'
    },
    stars: 30,
    destructionPercentage: 73.2
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: 'Trip to Walhall',
    tag: '#QPYC0QYJ',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png'
    },
    stars: 30,
    destructionPercentage: 66.53333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: '一群爷们在战斗',
    tag: '#PQYGYLPJ',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png'
    },
    stars: 43,
    destructionPercentage: 82.8
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: 'ubw',
    tag: '#9LY9YLQV',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png'
    },
    stars: 33,
    destructionPercentage: 78.66666666666667
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: '宝贝轻点',
    tag: '#2PU8GLGGL',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png'
    },
    stars: 8,
    destructionPercentage: 17.8
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: 'Trip to Walhall',
    tag: '#QPYC0QYJ',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png'
    },
    stars: 55,
    destructionPercentage: 100
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: 'blue vapor',
    tag: '#GJ98C29G',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png'
    },
    stars: 28,
    destructionPercentage: 68.73333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: 'Air Hounds 3',
    tag: '#2P9UG82L',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png'
    },
    stars: 39,
    destructionPercentage: 78.33333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: '雨过天晴',
    tag: '#R8JRUJCU',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png'
    },
    stars: 32,
    destructionPercentage: 76.6
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: '青春无敌',
    tag: '#9LLVCP9V',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png'
    },
    stars: 44,
    destructionPercentage: 80.6
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `Array.prototype.forEach()` on your players list. Then merge 2 objects with same tag to one :

```js
const list = [
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: '一群爷们在战斗',
    tag: '#PQYGYLPJ',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png'
    },
    stars: 2,
    destructionPercentage: 4.933333333333334
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: '雨过天晴',
    tag: '#R8JRUJCU',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png'
    },
    stars: 12,
    destructionPercentage: 35.13333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: '宝贝轻点',
    tag: '#2PU8GLGGL',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png'
    },
    stars: 3,
    destructionPercentage: 5.333333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: 'ubw',
    tag: '#9LY9YLQV',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png'
    },
    stars: 36,
    destructionPercentage: 80
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: 'Air Hounds 3',
    tag: '#2P9UG82L',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png'
    },
    stars: 15,
    destructionPercentage: 39.93333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: '青春无敌',
    tag: '#9LLVCP9V',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png'
    },
    stars: 4,
    destructionPercentage: 7.933333333333334
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: 'blue vapor',
    tag: '#GJ98C29G',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png'
    },
    stars: 30,
    destructionPercentage: 73.2
  },
  {
    state: 'inWar',
    name: 'Trip to Walhall',
    tag: '#QPYC0QYJ',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png'
    },
    stars: 30,
    destructionPercentage: 66.53333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: '一群爷们在战斗',
    tag: '#PQYGYLPJ',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/n6glPC-kovZwdM9gNds-44_DOtLB1W_qTX3DatIxUhc.png'
    },
    stars: 43,
    destructionPercentage: 82.8
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: 'ubw',
    tag: '#9LY9YLQV',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/sfoosjVYjGio8qL-ZrpLun6_jGI5pEFj40VJiL5c9YQ.png'
    },
    stars: 33,
    destructionPercentage: 78.66666666666667
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: '宝贝轻点',
    tag: '#2PU8GLGGL',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/qSKNpYBxc6bIsAETpUY3VZtd_-QkR9-HA7pMX8qYqsE.png'
    },
    stars: 8,
    destructionPercentage: 17.8
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: 'Trip to Walhall',
    tag: '#QPYC0QYJ',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/cKzBkIoyooJUnuLkleTZf74RKPmp4eS2G_5y7zyKeyo.png'
    },
    stars: 55,
    destructionPercentage: 100
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: 'blue vapor',
    tag: '#GJ98C29G',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/1C3HEUj_Jj0-TgKmxHinQzjss5qZ0Js0nGwFs60ICjk.png'
    },
    stars: 28,
    destructionPercentage: 68.73333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: 'Air Hounds 3',
    tag: '#2P9UG82L',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/VZWxMkdj9ayVb1eyrES7P4y_xBo9ZA_xxxxEt2KU9zc.png'
    },
    stars: 39,
    destructionPercentage: 78.33333333333333
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: '雨过天晴',
    tag: '#R8JRUJCU',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/oMZcD81pCMfJIzoOTT1OxsfaeRDRJyYxPB7IqrZcpfk.png'
    },
    stars: 32,
    destructionPercentage: 76.6
  },
  {
    state: 'warEnded',
    name: '青春无敌',
    tag: '#9LLVCP9V',
    badgeUrls: {
      small: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/70/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png',
      large: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/512/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png',
      medium: 'https://api-assets.clashofclans.com/badges/200/Z8Z1Er0uyqqaTAyDqsIh21SoIfs9WWFvmUgw8vH8jcw.png'
    },
    stars: 44,
    destructionPercentage: 80.6
  }
]


let reduced = {}

list.forEach(player => {
    if(!reduced[player.tag]){
    reduced[player.tag] = player
  }else{
    reduced[player.tag].stars +=player.stars
    reduced[player.tag].destructionPercentage += player.destructionPercentage
  }
})

console.log(`${list.length} objects reduced to ${Object.keys(reduced).length}`)
console.log(reduced)
```

Comment: Let me know if this is what you want to achieve

Comment: Yes man Tysm it worked like a boom. many many thanks man appreciate the help

Comment: Done bro again thanks for the help